# How to query length of days for reservation in Wix Velo

Tags: velo

Good day all,

I have zero experience with wix or velo, but I do some code writing and I got talked into trying to help someone with a problem.  We are trying to build in a custom price calculator based on the number of days a booking is scheduled for.  There are daily rates, weekly rates, and monthly rates and each one has different values. Any idea what I can query to determine the number of days that a booking is being requested for?  I can apply the pricing easy enough, I just can't figure out what the start and end dates are stored as to know which rate to assign.

I have been reading all the wix help stuff I can find and all the velo I can find.  I have found some examples for custom pricing, but nothing that shows me the dates or time values.